# Build x XOR (y XOR z) with NAND port

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I need to make  `x xor(y xor z)` with only NAND ports.
Notation: NOT(y) = ~y.

My first steps were to identify the output of that stuff, so:

`x xor(y xor z) = x xor (y~z + ~yz) = ~x(y~z + ~yz) + x~(y~z + ~yz) = ~xy~z + ~x~yz + x~y~z + xyz`

So the final output of my NAND construction should be: `~xy~z + ~x~yz + x~y~z + xyz`

I tried to attack this by first making y XOR z:

`y XOR z = y~z + ~yz = NAND[NAND(y,NAND(z,z)),NAND(z,NAND(y,y))]`

Since

`NAND(y,NAND(z,z)) = NOT(y * NOT(z*z)) = NOT(y) + z` which I'll call *g1* and

`NAND(z,NAND(y,y)) = NOT(z * NOT(y*y)) = NOT(z) + y` as *g2*

then the outside NAND[g1,g2] = z~y + y~z.

So now I have a XOR with just NANDs and doing the `x xor (y xor z)` should be just matter of treating (y xor z) as a single variable which gives me:

`x xor (y xor z) = NAND[NAND(x,NAND(NAND[NAND(y,NAND(z,z)),NAND(z,NAND(y,y))],NAND[NAND(y,NAND(z,z)),NAND(z,NAND(y,y))])),NAND(NAND[NAND(y,NAND(z,z)),NAND(z,NAND(y,y))],NAND(x,x))]`

Am I correct? I feel like the xor could be made in a more efficient way than using 5 NANDs ports.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final expression is correct.

The 20 `NAND` gates can be reduced to eight:

[image]

This circuit makes use of `XOR(x,y,z) = XOR(XOR(x,y),z)`. It is a combination of two two-input `XOR` gates, each of them composed  of four `NAND` gates.

Comment: At first glance seems that the major point it's implementing XOR(x,y) as NAND[NAND(X,NAND(X,Y)) , NAND(Y,NAND(X,Y))] which it's equal on paper 5 NANDs but when graphed since the share NAND(X,Y) you have 4 port. Then it's the same thing as mine, treating that input as a single variable and so 4+4 while mine, despite being 20 nands on paper should be 10 on circuit (following the same logic but I didn't circuit it). Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that's true.